# data sanitization/clean-up

Tags: sql, ms-access, sanitize

Just wondering…

We have a table where the data in certain fields is alphanumeric, comprising a 1-2 digit alpha followed by a 1-2 digit number e.g. x2, x53, yz1, yz95

The number of letters added before the number can be determined by the field so that certain fields will always have the same 1 letter added before the number while others will always have the same 2 letters.

For each field, the actual letters and number of letters added (1 or 2) are always the same, thus, we can always tell which letters appear before the numbers just via the field names.

For the purposes of all downstream data analysis, it is only ever the numeric value from the string which is important.

Sql queries are constructed dynamically behind a user form where the final sql can take many forms depending on which selections and switches the user has chosen. With this, the VBA generating the sql constructs is fairly involved, containing many conditions/variable pathways to the final sql construct.
With this, it would make the VBA and sql much easier to write, read, debug, and perhaps increase the sql execution speed, etc. – if we were only dealing with a numeric datatype e.g. I wouldn’t need to accommodate the many apostrophes within the numerous lines of “strSQL = strSQL & …”

Given that the data itself being analysed is a copy that’s imported via regular .csv extracts from a live source, would it be acceptable to pre sanitize/clean-up these fields around the import stage by converting the data within to numeric values and field datatypes? 
- perhaps either by modifying the sql used to generate the extract or by modifying the schema/vba process used to import the extract into the analysis table e.g. using something like a Replace function such as “ = Replace(OriginalField,”yz”,””) “  to strip out the yz characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, link the csv "as is", and for each linked table create a straight select query that does the sanitization, like:

```
 Select
      Val(Mid([Field1], 2)) As NumField1,
      Val(Mid([Field2], 1)) As NumField2,
        etc.
      Val(Mid([FieldN], 2)) As NumFieldN
 From
      YourLinkedCsvTable
```

then use this query throughout your application when you need the data.